# Tengo un problema con java socket en un programa de transferencia continua de archivos

Tags: java, socket, networking

Tengo un pequeño gran problema con java socket, en el cual deberia transferir archivos ida y vuelta entre el cliente y servidor, cada uno enviando un archivo en especifico.

Por ejemplo el Servidor tiene que enviar al cliente un archivo llamado test1 continuamente mientras que el cliente lo recibe, y el cliente deberia enviar el test2 y el servidor recibirlo.
Se que puede que no sea la mejor manera de hacerlo, pero con los cursos que hice es lo maximo a que puedo llegar por el momento.

El problema en si con mi codigo actual, es que despues de unos segundos (de 5 a 15 segundos) el programa deja de transferir archivos, se detiene sin mostrar errores en la consola que añadi.
El tiempo de 200 ms que le deje al programa es para "evitar saturar el socket" segun lei.
Este programa lo necesito para poder hacer un juego multijugador, dado que uso un motor un poco desfasado llamado Game-editor, el cual guarda las variables externamente en archivos sin extensión de 1kb, el cual no deberia ser mucho problema, espero sus respuestas :)

Intente revisar y cambiar la logica pero aun no logro nada.

ya que tiene una consola integrada, el servidor queda en Archivo enviado con exito.
y el cliente en Ronda completada.

Edit:
hice mas pruebas y note que si dejo el cliente y servidor activos transfiriendo archivos no tiene problemas, pero cuando los archivos que estan transfiriendo son modificados por el propio juego, empiezan los problemas

Este es el codigo del servidor, y a la mitad el codigo del cliente.
Pd. estoy usando netbeans la ultima version, no apache ni ningun otro.

````
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Server2 {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private static boolean isServerRunning = false;
    private static JTextArea logTextArea; 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        ImageIcon backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Maxo Marto\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Server2\\src\\server2\\4f8561c9272ff25516bcb7d23fea64ed.jpg");
        Image backgroundImage = backgroundIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(500, 210, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
            }
        };
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Maxo Marto\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Server2\\src\\server2\\Dsync.png");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("D-SyncMe Server");
        frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start Server");
        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop Server");

        startButton.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        stopButton.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        logTextArea = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        logTextArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(logTextArea);

        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!isServerRunning) {
                    startServer();
                    startButton.setEnabled(false);
                    stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });

        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isServerRunning) {
                    stopServer();
                    startButton.setEnabled(true);
                    stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        panel.add(startButton);
        panel.add(stopButton);
        panel.add(logScrollPane);
        panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        startButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        stopButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        startButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        stopButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    }

    private static void startServer() {
        isServerRunning = true;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
                    appendToLog("Conectando al puerto: 5000");
                    while (true) {
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        appendToLog(clientSocket + " Conectado.");
                        ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(clientSocket);
                        new Thread(clientHandler).start();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    appendToLog("Error en void RUN: " + e.getMessage()); 
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private static void stopServer() {
        isServerRunning = false;
        try {
            if (serverSocket != null) {
                serverSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            appendToLog("Error en void STOP: " + e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }

    private static class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        private DataInputStream dataInputStream;

        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (isServerRunning) {
                try {
                    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    appendToLog("Iniciando ronda.");
                    while (isServerRunning) {
                        sendFile("testa", dataOutputStream);

                        Thread.sleep(200);

                        receiveFile(dataInputStream, "testa2");

                        appendToLog("Ronda completada.");
                    }

                    dataInputStream.close();
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                    appendToLog("Se termino el servidor");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    appendToLog("Error en void RUN sendrevfile: " + e.getMessage()); 
                }
        }}
    }

    private static void sendFile(String path, DataOutputStream dataOutputStream) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(path);
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            dataOutputStream.writeLong(file.length());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
            }
            appendToLog("Archivo enviado con exito.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            appendToLog("Error al enviar archivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void receiveFile(DataInputStream dataInputStream, String fileName) throws Exception {
        int bytes = 0;
        try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
            long size = dataInputStream.readLong();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (size > 0 && (bytes = dataInputStream.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                size -= bytes;
            }
            appendToLog("Archivo recibido con exito.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            appendToLog("Error al recibir archivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void appendToLog(String message) {
        logTextArea.append(message + "\n");
        logTextArea.setCaretPosition(logTextArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }
    
}

//Y este es el codigo del cliente ------------------------------

     private static void appendToLog(String message) {
        logTextArea.append(message + "\n");
        logTextArea.setCaretPosition(logTextArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

   private static void startConnection() {
    String serverIP = ipTextField.getText().trim();
    if (serverIP.isEmpty()) {
        appendToLog("Introduzca una IP válida.");
        return;
    }
    isConnectionOpen = true;
     while (isConnectionOpen) {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(serverIP, 5000);
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        appendToLog("Conexión establecida.");

        while (isConnectionOpen) {
            receiveFile(dataInputStream, "testa");
            Thread.sleep(200);
            sendFile("testa2", dataOutputStream);
            appendToLog("Ronda completada.");
        }   

        appendToLog("El cliente ha terminado.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        appendToLog("Error de conexión: " + e.getMessage()); 
    }
}}
  private static void stopConnection() {
    isConnectionOpen = false;
    try {
        if (socket != null) {
            dataInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        appendToLog("El cliente ha terminado.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        appendToLog("Error al cerrar la conexión: " + e.getMessage()); 
    }
}

    private static void receiveFile(DataInputStream dataInputStream, String fileName) throws Exception {

       int bytes = 0;

        try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {

            long size = dataInputStream.readLong(); 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            
            while (size > 0 && (bytes = dataInputStream.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {

                fileOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bytes);
                size -= bytes;     
            }
            appendToLog("Archivo recibido con exito.");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            appendToLog("Error al recibir archivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void sendFile(String path, DataOutputStream dataOutputStream) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(path);
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {

            dataOutputStream.writeLong(file.length());

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                dataOutputStream.flush();

            }
            appendToLog("Archivo enviado con exito.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            appendToLog("Error al enviar archivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: y el log?? donde se queda???

Comment: realmente no se como hacer un log, la consola que integre solo muestra los mensajes que establecí, si te preguntas por los ultimos mensajes:
El servidor queda en Archivo enviado con exito.
y el cliente en Ronda completada.

Comment: Agrega mas mensajes... por ejemplo, en el cliente, en el principio del while de ronda completada, agrega un "inicio while"... a ver cuantas veces entras...para mi, estas saliendo de una de todos esos while...

Comment: " pero cuando los archivos que estan transfiriendo son modificados por el propio juego, empiezan los problemas" se llama deadlock.. hay dos programas tratando de acceder al mismo recurso, y como uno no lo suelta, el otro se queda esperando eternamente....

Comment: ¿Por qué reinventar la rueda? teniendo ftp y scp, incluso con http. El que hayas visto de primera mano la complejidad es muy valioso, ahora es momento de valorar alternativas.

Comment: Ya logré encontrar el problema, el tema de reinventar la rueda, es porque necesitaba de esa forma específica el programa, que transfiera de manera constante sin importar si el archivo había cambiado o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado gracias a gbianchi . El problema era que dos programas distintos intentaban acceder a un mismo recurso causando un deadlock.

La solución es comunicar ambos programas entre si, seguramente debe haber mejores formas, pero lo que yo hice fue que en el servidor/cliente luego de transferir, esperen hasta que el archivo sea modificado.
Usando una variable guardada externamente para que ambos programas la usen (ya que uno es Java y el otro un motor del 2001 sin ningún tipo de networking pero si Lee archivos externos).